# Flutter - How to Align (widget) grandchildren widgets the same as the child

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've looked for an answer all over google and s.o and couldn't find one to my likin'.

I'm using a Stack widget as my page layout. Inside that Stack, I'm positioning all the child widgets with Align widget. I've tried to create a ListView widget under my Align child, but its cards (children) are ignoring the ListView alignment at the alignment value I set to the List to start from.

```
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment(0, -0.28),
      child: Divider(
        color: Color.fromARGB(50, 255, 255, 255),
      ),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment(0, -0.20),
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            child: ListTile(
            leading: Icon(some_icon),
            title: Text("blabla"),
          )),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

I would expect the ListView items to start under my Divider, as the value set for the vertical alingement is -0.20 which is lower than the Divider alignment (-0.28).
But, here's how it looks:

[image]

If I remove the ListView and set the **Card widget as the Align direct child**, the positioning is fine.
Now, as I read in the documentation, the Align widget alignment values are respectable by it's **only child**, so how would I achieve the same for the ListView children (Rows/ListTiles/Card etc)?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a sample ! Modify as your requirement. (**Edited**)

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: [
      //Your behind widgets here...
      Stack(children: [
        Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            child:
                ListTile(title: Text('1st card', textAlign: TextAlign.center))),
        Align(
          alignment:Alignment(0, -0.20),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 2,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.black,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 25, left: 25),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
                width: double.infinity,
              ),
              Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: [
                    ListTile(
                        title: Text('List card', textAlign: TextAlign.center))
                  ])),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ])
    ]));
  }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I wanted to achieve. You have forced a "SizedBox" with height X to "push" the 2nd card down. However, I'm interested in how to make my ListView chlidren start from the Align widget values position, without "pushing" them downwards using another widget..

Comment: Thanks again but this includes a Card->ListView and not the other way, which is what I'm trying to figure out. Basically I want a ListView to start from Align position (x,y) and contain a Row/Card inside of it which will start relatively to the ListView start position and not at the top of the screen, with all of the above under a Stack widget.

Comment: Your sketch/layout above is not sufficient ! Provide a better pic that how do you want !

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...

```
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Divider(
                  thickness: 20, // this is for example
                  height: 22, // this is for example
                  color: Colors.red, // this is for example
                ),
                Card (
                    child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.print),
                  title: Text("blabla"),
                )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Hey chirag, tnx but I don't see any referemce to a ListView that holds a Card/Row. You can see my comment on the answer above you for a clearer explantion.